# Why do I get an error of node stack overflow with ggplot2 (R mapping)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, mapping, runtime-error

I am approaching map creation on R for the first time, I tried to extract this db, create a subset and plot it with ggplot but it gives me this error:

Error: node stack overflow
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
Error during wrapup: node stack overflow
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart

This is the script:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(geodata)
library(terra)
library(tidyterra)
library(ggplot2)

IT2 <- gadm(country = "ITA", level=2, path = tempdir())

unique(IT2[["NAME_1"]])

NW = subset(IT2,IT2$NAME_1=="Liguria" | IT2$NAME_1=="Piemonte"| IT2$NAME_1=="Valle d'Aosta", c("NAME_1", "NAME_2")) 

ggplot() + 
  geom_spatvector(data = NW, fill = NA, col = "black") +
  theme_void()
```

A simple map of three Italian regions should be created, but all I get is a blank screen and the reported error.

I have tried re-installing all the libraries I have to, restarting the PC and RStudio, freeing up RAM, cleaning the environment but I cannot find a solution.
It's a very simple process and NW is a space vector with only 13 rows and two columns, what do you think is the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I could not replicate your issue. 1) Can you plot IT2? If not, the problem may be because IT2 did not download correctly? So try getting the data again to see if the issue persists.  2) You could try writing the data to another directory instead of `tempdir()`. 3) The code that you posted does not require `tidyverse` to run. Having said that, I ran your code both with and without `tidyverse` and it still worked. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (https://github.com/dieghernan/tidyterra/issues/140), but I managed to fix it.

Apparently, the whole problem happened because of different GDAL installations and where the packages were looking for it.

You can check where your PROJ_LIB is getting its information `Sys.getenv("PROJ_LIB")`.

In my case, it was from an PostgreSQL folder. What I did was re-set the environmental variable from PROJ_LIB to the terra's database:

`Sys.setenv(PROJ_LIB="C:\\Users\\ly60anep\\AppData\\Local\\R\\win-library\\4.3\\terra\\proj")`

Once the change worked, it was not permanent, what I fixed adding the line to the .Rprofile, using:

`usethis::edit_r_profile()`

It also solved other problems I had related to re-projections, such as:

> Error: [project] output crs is not valid In addition: Warning message:
> PROJ: proj_create_from_database: C:\Program
> Files\PostgreSQL\13\share\contrib\postgis-3.1\proj\proj.db lacks
> DATABASE.LAYOUT.VERSION.MAJOR / DATABASE.LAYOUT.VERSION.MINOR
> metadata. It comes from another PROJ installation. (GDAL error 1)